# Solving $x^2u_x + y^2u_v + z(x+y)u_z = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

**Exercise :**

> Solve the PDE
>   $$x^2u_x + y^2u_v + z(x+y)u_z = 0$$

**Attempt :**

We have to solve the problem :

$$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{dy}{y^2} = \frac{dz}{z(x+y)}$$

Choosing the first two fractions, we yield :

$$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{dy}{y^2} \Rightarrow \int \frac{dx}{x^2} = \int \frac{dy}{y^2} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{y} + c $$
$$\implies $$
$$u_1 = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}$$

Now, choosing the first and the last fraction, we yield :

$$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{dz}{z(x+y)} \Rightarrow \int z(x+y)dx = \int x^2dz \Leftrightarrow z\frac{x^2}{2} + zxy = x^2z + c'  $$

but this is a different result for $u_2$ and eventually the general solution $u(x,y,z) = F(u_1,u_2)$ than Wolfram Alpha calculates [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20*%20d(u(x,y,z))%2Fdx%20%20%2B%20y%5E2%20*%20d(u(x,y,z))%2Fdy%20%2B%20z(x%2By)%20*%20d(u(x,y,z))%2Fdz%20%3D%200). Why is this the case and where am I wrong with my solution ?

Comment: @LutzL As I am a beginner in the PDE course, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: If the right side were not $0$ but some multiple of $u$, then $u$ is not constant along the characteristic curves. Here $=\frac{du}0$ just tells you that $u$ is also a constant which you already used in $u=F(u_1,u_2)$.

Comment: @LutzL Oh, understood ! We haven't been introduced to such cases yet, that's why I was unaware. Nice point though !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first equation

$$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{dy}{y^2} \Rightarrow \int \frac{dx}{x^2} = \int \frac{dy}{y^2} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{y} + C$$

$$ \implies  K=\frac 1x- \frac 1y $$
For the last equation use this trick @Rebellos

$$\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac{dy}{y^2} = \frac{dz}{z(x+y)}$$
$$\frac{dx-dy}{x^2-y^2} = \frac{dz}{z(x+y)}$$
$$\frac{d(x-y)}{x-y} = \frac{dz}{z}$$

I let you finish this last equation

Comment: Pretty cool trick, couldn't catch it ! Thanks for the nice heads up !

Comment: Yw @Rebellos ...it's more easy to integrate indeed